# Making a ndarray of two lists python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to do K- means clustering with scipy following this tutorial: http://glowingpython.blogspot.no/2012/04/k-means-clustering-with-scipy.html

The problem is that he uses vstack to make the arbitrary datapoints, which in turn returns an ndarray. I have two lists: lengths and breadths. How do I combine them to an ndarray so I can use his example?

```
lengths = [300.0, 300.0, 300.0, 300.0, 303.0, 300.0]
breadths = [9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 10.3, 6.8, 9.4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy's  `vstack` will just accept these as lists fine:

```
In [23]: np.vstack((lengths, breadths))
Out[23]:
array([[ 300. ,  300. ,  300. ,  300. ,  303. ,  300. ],
       [   9.6,    9.7,    9.8,   10.3,    6.8,    9.4]])
```

If you want to explicitely convert it to an array, you can do:

```
In [24]: np.array(lengths)
Out[24]: array([ 300.,  300.,  300.,  300.,  303.,  300.])
```

However, I think in the case of this example `kmeans` expects the observations as different rows, so you need the transpose: `np.vstack((lengths, breadths)).T`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems like something wrong is happening, as his data is an array of tuples where each tuple consist of each point [ [2 2] [2 4] [2 7] ] etc while this result gives two long arrays.

Comment: His data is a 2D array, where the columns are the different features (eg x, y, or length, breadth in your case). See my update.

Comment: I know gratitude should be shown by up-voting and accepting (which I have done) - but I just want also express my gratitude in words as well. Thank you.